# AWS API gateway to fetch records from multiple tables in a single API call

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, velocity, aws-api-gateway

I have two tables in DynamoDB both of which have same column/key "sessionid". Using AWS API gateway I want to fetch and display records from both tables when I pass the value for the column "sessionid"

Currently, my mapping template looks like below which is retrieving records from Table1 only:
Integration Request-

```
 {
    "TableName": "Table1",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "sessionid = :v1",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {
                "S": "$input.params('sessionid')"
               }
    }
 }
```

Integration Response-

```
 #set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
 {
     "Table1": [
         #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items) {
         "sessionid": "$elem.sessionid.S",
         "rowId": "$elem.rowId.S"
        }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
      ]
 }
```

How can I integrate the mapping for the second table "Table2" in the above mapping, so records from both tables are retrieved in a single API call?

Your suggestions will help.

Comment: Could you explain more specific?

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway can only make one single downstream API call. Unfortunately, it appears that DynamoDB API only supports a single Table for a scan/query/GetItem request. If you want to aggregate items from multiple tables, you would have to use a Lambda function between API GW and DDB.